# Error: "extension/package.json not found inside zip." when repackaging and installing VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've downloaded a VSIX extension for VSCode here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2

I've then tested this VSIX in VSCode and it installs, no problem.

At this point I then uninstall, rename the VSIX to a zip and then unzip to make edits.

The only edit I'm making is adding Indent rules in the Language config.

I then rezip (using macOS Finder) and rename to a VSIX file extension.

Upon trying to install again in VSCode I get the error "extension/package.json not found inside zip."

There is one at that path so I'm uncertain what the issue is.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think chances are that the repackaged `.zip` does not have the correct format. If you use the offical [`vsce`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsce) tool for this instead, the `.vsix` you end up with should definitely be valid.

First install it (requires NPM to be installed) with:

```
npm install -g vsce
```

Then you should be able to just switch to the directory where you've installed the extension (`~/.vscode/extensions/<name>`) and run:

```
vsce package
```

Comment: Hello @Gama11 can you take a look to my question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71815403/installing-code-graph-in-visual-studio-code-error-extension-package-json-not